# Mocked methods with Moq not getting called within code in Unity Play Mode Tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

If I mock a method, do I have to explicitly call that method to run my mocked implementation?

I'm trying to get mocking to work inside a Unity project. I'm basically starting a scene and within a Start() method, code executes. I'm trying to mock a rest call that happens within that start method.

Here's my code:

```
public class MyAddressablesClass
{
    public virtual IEnumerator LoadRemoteCatalog()
    {
        // My implementation here
    }
}

public class MyCode
{
    public IEnumerator Start()
    {
        // Doing some stuff
        MyAddressablesClass myAddressablesInstance = new MyAddressablesClass();
        yield return myAddressablesInstance.LoadRemoteCatalog();
        // Doing some other stuff
    }
}
```

Here's my mock implementation:

```
private IEnumerator GetFakeCatalog() {
    yield return null;
}

[UnitySetUp]
public IEnumerator Setup()
{
    Mock<MyAddressablesClass> mockedClass = new Mock<MyAddressablesClass>();
    mockedClass.Setup(service => service.LoadRemoteCatalog()).Returns(GetFakeCatalog());
}

[UnityTest]
public IEnumerator TestThings() {
    yield return SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync("MyScene");
}
```

When I run my unit test, I don't want to explicitly say `var mocked = new MyAddressablesClass(mockedClass.Object); yield return mocked.LoadRemoteCatalog();` in order for `GetFakeCatalog()` to get called.

Shouldn't it automatically use my mocked implementation any time `LoadRemoteCatalog()` is called within my actual code?

I'd like to test all of what happens when a scene starts up so I don't want to mock that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moq isn't magic; it'll only implement the test-specific behaviour on the object(s) you configure.

When, in the System Under Test (SUT), you write

```
MyAddressablesClass myAddressablesInstance = new MyAddressablesClass();
```

the SUT is going to use that `MyAddressablesClass` instance, just like the code says; not `mockedClass`.

That a test creates a `Mock<MyAddressablesClass>` is irrelevant. They're two different objects.

If you want to be able to change the behaviour of `MyAddressablesClass` inside of `MyCode.Start`, you'll have to somehow pass the object around.

Depending on requirements, I recommend either Constructor Injection or Method Injection.

In both cases, tests will now be able to pass `mockedClass.Instance` to the SUT.

## Constructor Injection

```
public class MyCode
{
    private readonly MyAddressablesClass myAddressablesInstance;

    public MyCode(MyAddressablesClass myAddressablesInstance)
    {
        this.myAddressablesInstance = myAddressablesInstance;
    }

    public IEnumerator Start()
    {
        // Doing some stuff
        yield return myAddressablesInstance.LoadRemoteCatalog();
        // Doing some other stuff
    }
}
```

## Method Injection

```
public class MyCode
{
    public IEnumerator Start(MyAddressablesClass myAddressablesInstance)
    {
        // Doing some stuff
        yield return myAddressablesInstance.LoadRemoteCatalog();
        // Doing some other stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know why it didn't occur to me that they were two separate instances of the object. Thanks for your help on this