# How to mock a call to external service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, moq, asp.net-core-7.0

I'm using ASP.NET Core 7.0 and I have a Web API.
I have a simple controller that looks like this:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/payment")]
public class PaymentController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ILogger logger;
    public PaymentController(ILogger logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpPost("createPayment")]
    public Task<MyResponse> CreatePayment([FromBody] PaymentInfo paymentInfo)
    {
        PaymentAction action = CreatePaymentAction(paymentInfo);
        Task<MyResponse> payload = action.Execute();
        return payload;
    }
}
```

`PaymentInfo` is a class that contains details about a certain payment.
`CreatePaymentAction` is a helper method that creates an object of type `PaymentAction`, and in this object there is the `Execute` method that inserts the payment details into a database.
`MyResponse` is a class I created to hold the response data.

Now I want to test my controller, but I don't really want to insert data into my database, so I want to mock this.

I tried something like this, using Moq:

```
[Fact]
public async Task CreatePaymentReturnsSuccessCode()
{
    // Arrange
    PaymentInfo paymentInfo = CreatePaymentInfo();
    StringContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(paymentInfo), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    
    Mock<PaymentAction> mockPaymentAction = new Mock<PaymentAction>();
    mockPaymentAction.Setup(m => m.Execute()).Returns(Task.FromResult(new MyResponse() { Message = "Success", Code = "200", Status = "Ok" }));

    // Assert
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("api/payment/createPayment", content);
    MyResponse responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<MyResponse>();

    // Act
    Assert.Equal("Success", responseContent.Message);
    Assert.Null(responseContent.Exception);
    Assert.Equal("Ok", responseContent.Status);
}
```

When I try to run the test, it actually insert a real data into the database and doesn't use the mock object.
Could someone help me figure out why and how to fix this?

Comment: You need to mock PostAsync.

Comment: Where and how is `client` defined in the test? With which web instance does it communicate? Are you using self-hosted testing (i.e. `WebApplicationFactory<TEntryPoint>`)?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: @MarkSeemann yes I am

Answer (score 1):

You [can't just define a Test Double in a unit test and expect it to replace the real dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77177269/126014). You'll need to somehow pass it to the System Under Test (SUT).

Since it seems that you use [WebApplicationFactory](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.testing.webapplicationfactory-1) to self-host the SUT, you can use its [ConfigureWebHost](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.testing.webapplicationfactory-1.configurewebhost) method to override injected dependencies. [Here's an example](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2021/01/25/self-hosted-integration-tests-in-aspnet/#db1185165dc748aba67c8daa6278f523).

If you wish to override the behaviour of `PaymentAction.Execute` from a unit test, you need to somehow be able to inject the `PaymentAction` object that `PaymentController` receives from `CreatePaymentAction`. Standard Constructor Injection is likely to be the easiest way to do that.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusiuon, my test is inherit from IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactory<Startup>>